# How does the Entity Framework walks through a collection that is too big?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqldatareader

I am new to Entity Framework.

And I have one concern:

I need to walktrhough a quite big amount of data that is gathered via a LINQ to Entities that combines couple of properties from different entities in an anonymous type.

If I need to read the returned items of this query one by one until the end, am I under the risk of OutOfMemory exception as the collection is BIG or EF uses SqlDataReader implicitly?

( Or should I use EntityDateReader to ensure that I am reading the Db in a sequential order (But then I have to generate my query as a string I guess) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see it there are  two things you can do, firstly turn off tracking  by using .AsNoTracking this will in most cases cut your memory set in half which may be enough.

If your set is still too big use skip and take to pull down the resultset in chunks. You should also use this in conjunction with AsNoTracking to ensure no memory is consumed with tracking

**EDIT:**

For example you could use something like the following the following to loop through all items in chunks of 1000. The below code should only hold 1000 items at a time in memory.

```
int numberOfItems = ctx.MySet.Count();

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItems + 1000; i+=1000)
{
    foreach(var item in ctx.MySet.AsNoTracking().Skip(i).Take(1000).AsEnumerable())
    {
         //do stuff with your entity
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry; what do you mean by 'use skip and take pull down the resultset in chunks' actually?

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of the data is as big as you said i would recommend that you don't use EF for such a case. EF is great but you sometimes need to fallback and use standard SQL to get better performance.

Take a look at Dapper.NET https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net

If you really want to use EF in every case i would recommend that you use a **Bounded Contexts** (multiple DBContexts).

Splitting your model in multiple smaller contexts will improve the performance as you will use less resources when EF creates an in-memory model of the context.

> The larger the context is the more resources are expended to generate
>   and maintain that in-memory model.

Also you can **Detach** and **Attach** when sharing instances of multiple context so you still don't load all the model.

Comment: This actually isn't a performance question but even if it was, the performance increases from using a platform such as dapper are not as substantial as you are suggesting. There is an approx 25% improvement in the bulk select performance of dapper over EF when using large data sets but I would call that fairly insignificant in computing terms. Take a look at my performance stats around this here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/03/entity-framework-comparative.html

Comment: In terms of actual memory usage there will be very little difference between dapper and EF without tracking. Im not too sure what you are meaning about bounded contexts as this is a DDD term which has nothing to do with performance or memory consumption and is much more concerned with logical separation. In addition reducing memory by using detach with EF isn't a good idea as by the time you call detach you have already consumed the memory. .AsNoTracking is a far better solution here as it means that memory is never allocated to the tracker.

Comment: Working with smaller contexts (separated by domain needs) reduces the memory as EF will consume less when creating an in-memory model of the context.

Comment: if he has to process the same amount of objects it will take the same amount of memory no matter how he divides it.